# ResultSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName returns UNKNOWN

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have a query for which the getColumnTypeName returned as **UNKNOWN**
but when **getColumnType** is invoked it return valid result **92** TIME

I've verified it from [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/recipes/ResultSet-ColumnType.shtml)

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","1234");
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select case when id>0 then last_day(date) else makedate(2015,1) end as date from emp.tabDate");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));//returns UNKNOWN
            System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnType(1));//returns 92
```

Is there a way i can get valid Type of the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Java Documentation on Constants of [***java.sql.Types***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql), the value `92` represents [***java.sql.TIME***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.TIME).

Your sql statement includes expression and the derived result must be of type `92` i.e. `java.sql.TIME`. If it is correct, then try to ***`CAST`*** the expression result as `TIME` and see the result.

**Example on CAST**:

```
select cast(
       case when id>0 
                 then last_day(date) 
                 else makedate(2015,1) 
        end as time ) as expr_res 
  from emp.tabDate
```

Also look into documentation on [***getColumnTypeName(int)***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnTypeName(int)). It says,

> If the column type is a user-defined type, then a fully-qualified type
>   name is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If [`getColumnType(int column)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType-int-) returns [`Types.DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#DATE) (`91`), then it means you should be calling [`getDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate-int-).

Naming convention is not that difficult to understand. If `getColumnType` returns `Types.XXXXX`, it means you should call `getXxxxx()`.

Simple enough, right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding you. The valid JDBC column type is `DATE`.